# Lightswitch Error Publishing on Windows Azure

Tags: azure, visual-studio-lightswitch

After having published a Visual Studio Lightswitch 2013 Application to Windows Azure as a Desktop Client I receive a Load operation failed for query 'Login' An error occurred when parsing the Cookie header for Uri…

The actual screenshot can be viewed at the following location:

[1]: http://screencast.com/t/yxXDdNUoI Screenshot 1

Also the tracing results can be viewed at the following screenshots:

[1]: http://screencast.com/t/39HChZjr1I Screenshot 2

[1]: http://screencast.com/t/9xwUtBO8UPMI Screenshot 3

Unfortunately the tracing doesn't seem to be telling me anything unless I'm missing something…

Thanks Mark

Comment: If I disable authentication then it works even in desktop mode.

If I reapply authentication back to square one.

Tried dropping all the ASP membership objects in the database but still have the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed the setting in the web.config file for authentication

The application name had a space
once space had been removed everything worked properly again

Answer (score 0):

Good Day,

all what you have to do is look for the Authentication mode in Web.config, once there, you will see the application name, if there's a space between the two names, just delete the space and make the name as one, works like a charm!